# How do I set font size of the figure title in gnuplot-py?

Tags: python, gnuplot

I have a working plot with this title:

```
g.title('eta_n as a Function of Time')
```

The default font size is fine for axis labels, but I want a larger size for the plot title.

```
g.title('eta_n as a Function of Time', font=',18') failed.
```

I'm working on an imac screen with terminal set to 'aqua'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gnuplot-py` uses a very old syntax for setting the title's font which was already deprecated with version 4.4. Until version 4.6 this syntax could be enabled using a flag at compile time, but since version 5.0 the syntax isn't supported any more.

You must send the complete command to get it working:

```
g('set title "eta_n as a Function of Time" font ",18"')
```

Comment: This removes the error in the Python code, but the change in font size still doesn't happen.

Comment: Christoph, your solution worked only after I specified a font.g('set title "eta_n as a Function of Time" font "courier,18"')